# f.for loop to read out a directory

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

With the following code in my TYPO3 partials.html I try to read out each element in fileadmin/images directory:

```
<h2>{gallery.title}</h2>
<h3>{gallery.recordingDay -> f:format.date(format: "d.m.Y")}</h3>
<p>{gallery.description}</p>


<table class="tx-gallery">
    <tr>
        <f:for each="{gallery.image}" as="images">
            <td>
                <f:image src="fileadmin/images/{image.file}" />
            </td>
        </f:for>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Title, recordingday and description returns a value, but only my for-loop returns broken-image symbol. Can anybody give me a hint, whats's wrong???

Thanks

Comment: Consider using DevTools in your browser. I'd assume the path to the image resource is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you have to access the items as specified in the `as` property of the `f:for`.

You specified `as="images"`.

Therefore you have to access your images inside the loop with `{images.file}`.

I suggest to go for `as="image"` instead as that is better readable.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your quick response. I changed the code as you described:                                                                                                             
...
  <f:for each="{gallery.image}" as="images">
   ..
     <f:image src="fileadmin/images/{images.file}" />
...
but now i get an error Oops, an error occurred! Code: 201703231300260803da5c

Comment: Set your instance to debug mode in the install tool (configuration presets) to get a more meaningful error message. That should help you to identify the issue.

Comment: I set it to debug mode, but i didn't get any issue! see under http://www.nikahodasi.com/index.php?id=5

Comment: add this typoscript in setup geting proper error  **config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0**